# Linear differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am wondering if MA can solve this system of linear ODEs analytically

```
DSolve[{Derivative[1][y[1]][t] == U - 2 I y[2][t] + 2 I y[4][t], 
        Derivative[1][y[2]][t] == -I y[1][t] + I x[t] y[2][t] - I y[3][t] + 2 I y[5][t], 
        Derivative[1][y[3]][t] == -2 I y[2][t] + 2 I x[t] y[3][t] + 2 I y[6][t], 
        Derivative[1][y[4]][t] == I y[1][t] - I x[t] y[4][t] - 2 I y[5][t] + I y[7][t], 
        Derivative[1][y[5]][t] == I y[2][t] - I y[4][t] - I y[6][t] + I y[8][t], 
        Derivative[1][y[6]][t] == I y[3][t] - 2 I y[5][t] + I x[t] y[6][t] + I y[9][t], 
        Derivative[1][y[7]][t] == 2 I y[4][t] - 2 I x[t] y[7][t] - 2 I y[8][t], 
        Derivative[1][y[8]][t] == 2 I y[5][t] - I y[7][t] - I x[t] y[8][t] - I y[9][t], 
        Derivative[1][y[9]][t] == U + 2 I y[6][t] - 2 I y[8][t]}, 
        {y[1], y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5], y[6], y[7], y[8], y[9]}, t]
```

The matrix of coefficients is rather simple and eigenvalues can easily be found. In fact we can write
$$
\dot{\vec{y}}(t)=A\cdot \vec{y}(t)+b
$$
with

```
A={{0, 2 I, 0, -2 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {I, -I x[t], I, 0, -2 I, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 2 I, -2 I x[t], 0, 0, -2 I, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {-I, 0, 0, I x[t], 2 I, 0, -I, 0, 0}, 
   {0, -I, 0, I, 0, I, 0, -I, 0}, 
   {0, 0, -I, 0, 2 I, -I x[t], 0, 0, -I}, 
   {0, 0, 0, -2 I, 0, 0, 2 I x[t], 2 I, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, -2 I, 0, I, I x[t], I}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2 I, 0,  2 I, 0}}
b={U, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, U}
```

Function `x[t]` is a parameter and `U` is a constant. I know the system is  solvable in principle. If solution is unfeasible, I would be nice to at least reformulate the system by reducing the number of equations at the cost of increasing order. This is equivalent to bringing `A` to a block-diagonal form. Already this would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What is x[t]?  Is it an additional function?

Comment: IS x[t] known? If yes, please specify it. Otherwise, it needs an additional equation.

Comment: @DanielHuber Imagine a simpler case $\dot y(t)=x(t) y(t)+c$. This equation can be [solved analytically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation) even though the function $x(t)$ is not given explicitly. I want to achieve the same for my bigger system.

Comment: I think this can only be solved formally. There will be an integral of an unspecified function in the solution.

Comment: @DanielHuber Yes, it is fine. How do I get a formal solution that can be used elsewhere?  I need to substitute it in another function.

Comment: Have you tried it with dim(A) = {2,2}? Unless `DSolve` has been extended, it's been rather limited what it can do with high-order/high-dimensional systems.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I modified one example (2x2) in the documentation. If a parameter `x[t]` is in the free term, MA can solve. If it goes into `A` -- no solution. I guess the only hope is to bring A into a block-diagonal form. Somehow I feel it is possible because the eigenvalues have `Sqrt` like in the diagonalization of a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: There is  one simple first integral, although it may not help much.  `y[5][t] + (y[1][t] + y[9][t])/2 = U t +C[1]`.

Comment: `DSolve` won't solve this form of linear DE with `A = {{t, 1}, {1, t}}`, which has the solution $y = e^A \cdot \int e^{\int A\,dt \cdot b}$, so I think it's probably hopeless.

Comment: @MichaelE2  It seems to me that the question is whether the system of nine ODEs can be solved, even in principle, in terms of known functions rather than whether it can be solved by `DSolve` .  The former is, of course, a mathematics question rather than a Mathematica question.  It would be helpful to know the definition of `x[t]`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I took the question to be whether Mathematica can solve the system in terms of an unknown, time-dependent coefficient `x[t]`. It doesn't do it in a special, solvable case, which leads me to surmise it won't handle a more general, higher-dimensional case.